# Docker bind mount Docker Daemon on WINDOWS

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-daemon

Hello i am following a tutorial on DOCKER. But it is on Linux Environement, actually i use DOCKER on WINDOWS.

The purpose is to create an image bind to unix socket with alpine image :

```
docker container run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine
```

and run a call to Docker Daemon with CURL from the Alpine Shell :

```
curl -X POST –unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -d '{"Image":"nginx:1.12.2"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost/containers/create
```

But i am on windows ... i tryed :

```
docker container run --rm -it -v //./pipe/docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine alpine
```

But i can't connection :/

and i don't know how to modify the CURL request.

I already checked :

```
Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS

Exposing daemon on TCP without TLS helps legacy clients connect to the daemon. It also makes yourself vulnerable to remote code execution attacks. Use with caution.
```

Thank you for helping me :/

Comment: What do you expect `//.` to mean, both on the host and inside the container?

Comment: @tripleee 
Host is my Windows Machine Physical. 
And the container will be an Alpline Container, 
( i expect nothing :p i am completly beginner, i tryed many syntaxe found :/ )

Comment: We can't tell you what to put there if we can't understand what you _want_ it to mean.

Comment: @tipleee i just want to be able to use de DOcker API from my container and creer througth this an other container
like this
curl -X POST –unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -d '{"Image":"nginx:1.12.2"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost/containers/create

Comment: Well if `//./pipe/docker_engine` is correct on the host side (which I have no idea about; I luckily don't have any access to Windows) at a minimum that should be mapped to `/var/run/docker.sock` inside the container, so `-v //./pipe/docker_engine:/var/run/docker.sock`; but where is the socket _actually_ on your Windows host, if it is exposed at all?